# ORDER BY first OR condition true

Tags: mysql, sql-order-by

I have the folloing table in a MySQL 5.6+ database

```
+----+-------+-------+--------------+--------------+
| id | mood1 | mood2 | mood1_visual | mood2_visual |
+----+-------+-------+--------------+--------------+
|  1 |     5 |     7 |           5c |           7a |
|  2 |     5 |     7 |           5b |           7b |
|  3 |     5 |     7 |           5c |           7d |
|  4 |     5 |     8 |           5a |           8a |
|  5 |     5 |     7 |           5c |           7a |
|  6 |     5 |     8 |           5b |           8a |
+----+-------+-------+--------------+--------------+
```

I need to select rows where

```
(`mood1_visual`='5c' AND `mood2_visual`='7a') OR 
  (`mood1`=5 AND `mood2`=7 AND (`mood1_visual`<>'5c' OR `mood2_visual`<>'7a'))
```

In the example above those would be the rows 1,2,3 and 5. However I need them sorted with the ones that match the first part of the `WHERE` clause before the others, i.e. I need them sorted 1,5,2,3, because row 1 and row 5 satisfy the first part of the `WHERE` clause

```
(`mood1_visual`='5c' AND `mood2_visual`='7a')
```

How do I tell that in the `ORDER BY` clause? Is there anything like

```
ORDER BY THE ONES THAT MATCH CONDITION FIRST THEN THE OTHERS ?
```

Please note that 5,1,2,3 or 1,5,3,2 or 5,1,3,2 are all valid sortings for my needs, just in case that made the solution easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL can `order by` arbitrary expressions, e.g.

```
ORDER BY (foo = bar)
```

The boolean result of that will be typecast to an integer `0` or `1`, so if you want all of the "equal" values first (`1`), then

```
ORDER BY (foo = bar) DESC
```

and if you want all of the false (`0`) values first, then

```
ORDER BY (foo = bar) ASC
```

Comment: I only wonder how you managed to answer that fast... thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

What if you use `CASE` expression with `ORDER BY` like

```
ORDER BY 
    CASE 
        WHEN (`mood1_visual`='5c' AND `mood2_visual`='7a') THEN id 
    END
```